How to solve $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{\sin(e^{3x}-1)-3x}$ without L'Hopital?
I am not very good at mathematical analysis, I am missing certain gaps and I don't know who to consult.
I apologize because I don't know the code to write functions in a more visible way.
I have the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{\sin(e^{3x}-1)-3x}.$$
It is an exercise that appeared in a university exam last year and I have no idea how to solve it, can someone guide me?
Edit I made a mistake in my question, I apologize, I'm quite tired, the numerator is $x\sin x$, not $\sin x$. So, the limit I am interested in is
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin x}{\sin(e^{3x}-1)-3x}.$$

Please format your formulas

Why the university is asking high school level questions?

Is the limit from the left or from the right?

What is your definition of $e^x$?

because not all high schools in the world teach mathematical analysis.
The exercise does not specify the approximation side, it simply says: "solve the following limit"


As $x\to0$, $\sin x\sim x$ (which means: $\frac{\sin x}x\to1$).
As $u\to0$, $v:=e^u-1\sim u$, and $(\sin v)-u=\sin v-\ln(1+v)\sim\frac{v^2}2$, since $\sin v=v+o(v^2)$ and $\ln(1+v)=v-\frac{v^2}2+o(v^2)$.

Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin x}{\sin(e^{3x}-1)-3x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{(3x)^2/2}=\frac29.$$

Forgive my ignorance, but I wrote this function in Geogebra, and it seems to me that the vertical asymptote is closer to 3/9 than 2/9, but perhaps the software is imprecise.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Csin+x%7D%7B%5Csin%28e%5E%7B3x%7D-1%29-3x%7D+as+x-%3E0 confirms $2/9$. The "vertical asymptote" you are talking about has nothing to do with this limit.

It doesn't matter, maybe I'm missing theory, I'm not very good at this, I'll take the answer as good and try to understand it, thanks for the help

The "vertical asymtote" corresponds to the positive value of $x$ for which the denominator is $0$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csin%28e%5E%7B3x%7D-1%29%3D3x

ohhh sorry, you're right, I got confused, I just checked the geogebra again, it's approximately 2/9... Sorry, I think I'm tired.
Thanks for clarifying the doubt, and thanks for helping with the exercise, at least now I have a clear answer.

Excuse me @AnneBauval I've seen this expansion of log series and sine series a lot. Can you please tell me what are they? I know the basic of limits, since I learnt it a few months ago. I reached till your point until I couldn't solve $$\sin v - \log(1+v)$$ as if I divide them both by $v$ then the denominator is getting zero, which can't be considered. Thanks in advance

$\sin v=v+o(v^2)$, i.e. $v+$ something which tends to $0$ faster than $v^2$, is the first term of the Taylor series of $\sin v$. Similarly, $\ln(1+v)=v-\frac{v^2}2+o(v^2)$ is the beginning of the Taylor series of $\ln(1+v)$.

@AnneBauval Thanks a lot. Can you please clarify my doubt please. I started learning about them, but I can't understand the difference between Taylor series and Maclaurin series. Is Maclaurin series the same as Taylor series when $x=0$? I'm still in highschool so this is a bit confusing :")

@Gwen Exactly! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series (And I should have specified twice  "at $0$" in my previous comment.)

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin x}{\sin(e^{3x}-1)-3x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}x}{\frac{\sin(e^{3x}-1)-3x}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}x}{\frac{(e^{3x}-1)+O((e^{3x}-1)^3)-3x}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}x}{\frac{\frac12(3x)^2+O(x^3)}{x^2}}=\frac29.$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin x}{\sin(e^{3x}-1)-3x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin x}{x(\sin(e^{3x}-1)-3x)}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\frac{\sin(e^{3x}-1)\cdot (e^{3x}-1)}{e^{3x}-1}-3x}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{e^{3x}-1-3x}$$
Now use the fact that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

I made a mistake in my question, I apologize, I'm quite tired, the numerator is xsinx, not sinx
Anyway, how did you eliminate the sin from the denominator? And is that a taylor series?

Yes...it is the Taylor series

Apply the same approach in the real question as well

While I understand what you're getting at, your manipulations for the steps are wrong. You cannot take "partial" limits unless you can factor them out or otherwise isolate them from the rest of the terms.

@NinadMunshi but then why do they give correct answers?? I never understood this although ik that it is not mathematically correct

They don't always give correct answers you just got lucky. For example had the numerator been $x^2\sin x$ you would've been missing a lot of terms. If you want to leave an answer up you should do it properly.

@NinadMunshi why?? It will be just x^3 in the numerator....and both of those expressions yeild 0

@poison25 edit your OP to reflect the corrected question

I'm a little confused, how did the sines disappear in the numerator and denominator in the third and fourth steps?

The replacement of $\sin x$ by $x$ in the numerator was legit (because $\sin x/x\to1$), but the method for the denominator happens to give the right answer only by luck, as @NinadMunshi commented: " You cannot take "partial" limits unless you can factor them out or otherwise isolate them from the rest of the terms." You cannot just write (with the notations of my answer) $(\sin v)-u=\frac{\sin v}vv-u\sim1v-u$ just like that. Especially because $v\sim u$.

Indeed, that was my confusion, until now I have only done limits by converting the approximations without changing the function, I had never seen this done partially, so is it legitimate to partially approximate the variable or not?

No, @poison25, it is not. Again: as written at the moment, this answer is flawed. It only gives the right answer by luck.  Here is a counterexample to this erroneous reasoning: $x+x^2\sim x$ but $$(x+x^2)-(x-x^2)\not\sim x-(x-x^2).$$

got it, thank you!
